# Cmd prompt vs other shells

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to learn how to create a makefile and I faced couple of issues related to commands which I should use.

1. ls is something i know to list directories.
2. rm is something I know to remove file or directory and some other.

Then I learnt that Unix-cmd is different from command prompt in windows and also from powershell.

I'm using Windows 11 to create a make file. and I found alternate commands for the above like

1. dir /a:b, instead of ls
2. erase instead of rm.

What is the difference btw these shells and where to find them?

**Makefile**:

```
print: $(wildcard *.c)
    ls -la $?
```

**Error I got:**
ls

```
'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

I want to know a little more info about them.
Also what makes are available something which gives some overview. Names are sufficient.

Comment: On Windows, use [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075)'s `make`. It gives you the same environment as you'd get on any other platform (`sh` shell, and the commands you'd normally see on *nix).

Comment: Your terminology is confused. `cmd.exe` is specifically the legacy Windows command interpreter. The command interpreter on Unlix-like systems is usually called the "shell".

Comment: `make` as such does not require you to write recipes in any particular language, but the overwhelming standard practice is for `Makefile`s to use `sh` specifically. If you wanted to learn Make at your own leisure, using `cmd` as your local shell for playing around should be fine.

Comment: Windows out of the box does not have `sh`, though you can install it if you want to. A common arrangement is to install Git, which includes Bash, which is backwards-compatible with POSIX `sh`

Comment: @tripleee: I agree. I'm very new to software development, but learning at quite good speed. So to conclude, cmd.exe is a windows command interpreter and shell is a *nix (unix) command interpreter.

Comment: A shell means a command interpreter. Cmd, Powershell, sh, and others are shells.